# How to change UICollectionViewCell size programmatically (with Xib)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` along with a Xib which defines a size for the cell (60 pts by 60 pts).

I also implemented the following:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = [MainScreen screen];
    CGFloat width = size.width;
    CGFloat item = (width*60)/320;
    return CGSizeMake(item, item);
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that every time I run my program, the cells in my `UICollectionView` controller always appear as 60x60 cells.  Furthermore, I've been testing on an iPhone 6s which is 375x667 points (so, doing the math, the cells should be ~70x70 not 60x60).

How do I programmatically change the size of the cell (or, rather, override the predefined Xib size)?

Comment: did you make sure your view controller is set as the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate?

Comment: Yes, and by that I'm assuming you mean the following:  `[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];`, `[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];`

Comment: Actually, I take that back...the view controller is set to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in the header file.

Comment: I would try setting a breakpoint inside that method and make sure it's getting hit. The code looks fine to me? I would also try hard-coding the CGSize that is returned to make sure it's actually being set correctly and isn't an error in the lines above the return statement.

Comment: I added the breakpoint and took a look at the values...everything seems to check out.  The item size is ~70x70 which is exactly what it's supposed to be.  Any other suggestions?  I'm kind of baffled that my implementation of `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` isn't working.

Comment: I hard coded `CGSizeMake(100, 100)` and it affected the cell boundaries...however, the actual image size (which, in the Xib file is set to 60x60) still didn't change.

Comment: When I `NSLog` the frames of the cells created, they all register ~70x70 in height and width.  I noticed that if I shrink it to 40x40, the image size itself doesn't change, but the cell size does.  So most of the image gets cut off but the cell does shrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just inexperience showing on my end.  `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` was working properly, however the actual frame of the cell image needed to be redefined based on the `item` parameters.  So if I hard coded `CGSizeMake(100,100)` for the size of my collection view cell, I needed to also resize the image frame that would occupy the cell to 100x100.

Comment: glad you figured it out!